# linq marge duplicate values

Tags: c#, linq, list

I get a question and have no idea about it ....
I have a list here called `list<Promotion>`
The structure of Promotion is like this:

```
new promotion()
{
    string id,
    money amount,
    date startDate,
    date endDate
}
```

The many elements of this list is like this,

```
list[0] = {id =1, amount = 2, startDate = 2015-10-14, endDate= 2015-12-31}
list[1] = {id =1, amount = 3, startDate = 2015-11-01, endDate= 2015-11-15}
list[2] = {id =3, amount = 10, startDate = 2015-11-01, endDate= 2015-12-01}
list[3] = {id =5, amount = 32, startDate = 2015-11-01, endDate= 2015-12-01}
```

So I want to merge list[0] and list[1] together but also keep list[2] and list[3], the result will be something like this

```
list[0] = {id =1, amount = 5, startDate = 2015-10-14, endDate= 2015-11-15}
list[1] = {id =3, amount = 10, startDate = 2015-11-01, endDate= 2015-12-01}
list[2] = {id =5, amount = 32, startDate = 2015-11-01, endDate= 2015-12-01}
```

Because list[0] and list[1] has the same id, they are merged. I want to add amount together, and keep the lower date time for both startDate and endDate. After merging list[0] and list[1] become list[0]. And list[2] and list[3] became list[1] and list[2]

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: You should explain a little more your criteria for merging.  Looks like sum amount and take earliest start date and earliest end date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a simple group by query like this:

```
var promotions = new List<Promotion>();
promotions.Add(new Promotion { Id = 1, Amount = 2, StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 10, 14), EndDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 31) });
promotions.Add(new Promotion { Id = 1, Amount = 3, StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 11, 01), EndDate = new DateTime(2015, 11, 15) });
promotions.Add(new Promotion { Id = 3, Amount = 10, StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 11, 01), EndDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 01) });
promotions.Add(new Promotion { Id = 5, Amount = 32, StartDate = new DateTime(2015, 11, 01), EndDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 01) });

promotions = promotions.GroupBy(p => p.Id).Select(p => new Promotion
    {
        Id = p.Key,
        Amount = p.Sum(i => i.Amount),
        StartDate = p.Min(i => i.StartDate),
        EndDate = p.Min(i => i.EndDate)
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

First group them by the id. Then for each Group, select a new element according to your rules:

```
IEnumerable<promotion> merged = list.GroupBy(p => p.id)
  .Select(g => new Promotion
    {
      id = g.Key,
      amount = g.Sum(p => p.amount),
      startDate = g.Min(p => p.startDate),
      endDate = g.Min(p => p.endDate)
    };
```

(Note that lower-case property and class names is not the usual convention in .Net. It's technically fine, but not the style generally used).